# How can I draw points on my mobile and then pass it to my computer?

Tags: shapefile, mobile, data-collection

we are doing a survey to know how many people still use outside bathrooms in the Caribbean, I want to go house by house using a shapefile image on mobile and point the location of points of interest in different houses and them merge all this info on the PC, is there a way to do this?

Comment: Hello, welcome to GIS.SE, have you had a look at the resources in the following questions?
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6720/mobile-data-collection-options
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/94362/field-data-collection-tool?rq=1